# Homology and Exact Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have this exact sequence: $$0\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} H_k(X,C)\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} H_k(X,A)\stackrel{h}{\rightarrow} 0$$

Can I say that $H_k(X,A)=H_k(X,C)$ and why?

Please;

Thank you.

Comment: Think about what an exact sequence means. In particular, from the sequence what can you say about the arrow between $H_k(X,C)$ and $H_k(X,A)$?

Comment: $i:0\rightarrow H_k(X,C)$ et $j:H_k(X,C)\rightarrow H_k(X.A)$ the sequence is exact it means that $Im~i=\ker j$

Comment: Ahhh ok $j$ is bijectiv sinc $Im i=0=ker j$ and $j$ is surjectiv

Comment: I added function names so that you could talk about the kernel and image of the various maps, but I think you've got it!

Comment: $H_k(X,A)\cong H_k(X,C)$ is the idea

Answer (score 3):

This is probably one of the most important relationships you'll use when working with exact sequences - partly because it's an easy relationship to use, without considering the actual maps involved, which can often get tricky when the maps are induced by a functor.

Let $0\to G\to H\to 0$ be a short exact sequence. The image of $0\to G$ is trivial because the domain of the map is trivial, and so by exactness the map $G\to H$ has trivial kernal and so is injective.

The kernel  of the map $H\to 0$ is the whole of $H$ because the codomain is trivial and so by exactness the image of the map $G\to H$ is the whole of $H$ and so is surjective. It follows that $G\to H$ is an isomorphism.